# Need to add select fields to MsgBox jquery

Tags: jquery, msgbox

I need to add select fields to MsgBox with jQuery. Does anyone know how ?

```
if (input.type == 'checkbox')
{
    iLabel = input.label ? '<label class="' + this.options.name + '-label">' : '';
    fLabel = input.label ? input.label + '</label>' : '';
    input.value = input.value === undefined ? '1' : input.value;
    iName  = input.name === undefined ? this.options.name + '-label-' + i : input.name;
    this.esqueleto.inputs.append($(iLabel + '<input type="' + input.type + 
        '" style="display: inline; width: auto;" name="' + iName + '" value="' + 
        input.value + '" autocomplete="off"/>' + fLabel));
}
```

I changed it to select fields, but it does not work when communicating PHP > jQuery and vice versa.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (input.type == 'checkbox') {
    iLabel = input.label ? '<label class="' + this.options.name + '-label">': '';
    fLabel = input.label ? input.label + '</label>': '';
    input.value = input.value === undefined ? '1': input.value;
    iName = input.name === undefined ? this.options.name + '-label-' + i: input.name;
    this.esqueleto.inputs.append($(iLabel + '<input type="' + input.type + '" style="display:inline; width:auto;" name="' + iName + '" value="' + input.value + '" autocomplete="off"/> ' + fLabel))
} else if ( input.type == 'select' ) {
    iLabel = input.label ? '<label class="' + this.options.name + '-label">' + input.label: '';
    fLabel = input.label ? '</label>': '';
    input.value = input.value === undefined ? '': input.value;
    iName = input.name === undefined ? this.options.name + '-select-' + i: input.name;
    this.esqueleto.inputs.append($(iLabel + '<select name="' + iName + '"></select>' + fLabel));
    $.each(input.options, $.proxy(function(ip, ap) {
        ap.value = ap.value === undefined ? '': ap.value;
        iName = ap.name === undefined ? this.options.name + '-option-' + ip: ap.name;
        $('select[name=' + input.name + ']').append($('<option value="' + ap.value + '">' + ap.label + '</option>'))
    }, this));
}

inputs  : [
    { type: "select", name: "select", label: "select:", options: [{ label: "option1", value: "option1" },{ label: "option2", value: "option2" }] }
]
```

Find this line in the Javascript code:

```
this.close(this.toArguments($('input', this.esqueleto.inputs)))
```

and add `, select` as a jQuery selector to get this:

```
this.close(this.toArguments($('input, select', this.esqueleto.inputs)))
```

and CSS:

```
.jquery-msgbox-inputs select
{
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin: 3px 0 6px 0;
    width: 97%;
}
```